# how to find the implicit function or variables in scala

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I can't find the implicit conversions or implicit argument values being used in Scala code. This makes reading open source projects very confusing.

The `implicitly` trick can only help to check if there is a valid implicit variable of some type, but couldn't tell where the implicit variable was defined.

```
scala> implicitly[(Int) => RichInt]
res2: Int => scala.runtime.RichInt = <function1>
```

Is there an easy way to find the definitions of the implicit conversions and values being used by a piece of code? If the source code file is very long, it will be a huge work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One trick that has been covered on SO:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime._,universe._
import reflect.runtime._
import universe._

scala> reify { "abc".size }
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[Int] = Expr[Int](Predef.augmentString("abc").size)
```

Recent REPL:

```
scala> 3 until 4 //print<hit tab completion>
   scala.Predef.intWrapper(3).until(4) // : scala.collection.immutable.Range
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Scala Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA. The implicit conversions are underlined like this (where `Int 1` is converted to `BigInt`):

[image]

The above example is taken from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/working-with-scala-implicit-conversions.html?origin=old_help#highlight. You can read more on that page.